# How to Fix: Non-Differentiable Functions in my Custom RNN Cell

Tags: python-3.x, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am building a custom RNN cell where I want to update only a fraction of the states during each step. The keras model is built, but I am getting an error that the gradients are non-differentiable. This makes sense, due to using the tf.gather_nd and tf.scatter_nd functions, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get around this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Currently using TF2.0 and custom keras layers.

The following code shows the call function in the custom RNN cell. There is essentially a bypass for the majority of the states around the step in the cell.

```py
    def call(self, inputs, state):
        u, p = inputs
        state = state[0] + tf.zeros((state[0].shape))
        u = tf.reshape(u, (u.shape[0],self.players*2*(self.outputs+1),1))
        xp = self.get_game_states(state, p)
        xp_plus = tf.matmul(self.A, xp) + tf.matmul(self.B, u)
        state = self.update_states(state, p, xp_plus, xp)
        return state, [state]

    def get_game_states(self, states, players_in_game):
        batch_size = players_in_game.shape[0]
        state = tf.stack([tf.gather_nd(states[i], players_in_game[i]) for i in range(batch_size)],axis=0)
        state = tf.reshape(state, (batch_size, self.player_states*self.players*2, 1))
        return state

    def update_states(self, states, players_in_game, xp_plus, xp):
        state_change = xp_plus - xp
        state_change = tf.reshape(state_change, ((state_change.shape[0], self.players*2,-1)))
        sparse_tensor = tf.stack([tf.scatter_nd(players_in_game[i], state_change[i], states[0].shape) for i in range(states.shape[0])])
        states = states + sparse_tensor
        return states
```

ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.